# Python ValueError: not allowed to raise maximum limit

Tags: python, memory, stack-overflow

I'm using python 2.7.2 on mac os 10.7.3

I'm doing a recursive algorithm in python with more than 50 000 recursion levels.

I tried to increase the maximum recursion level to 1 000 000 but my python shell still exit after 18 000 recursion levels.

I tried to increase the resources available  :

```
import resource 
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (2**29,-1))
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
```

and I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#58>", line 1, in <module>
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK,(2**29,-1))
ValueError: not allowed to raise maximum limit
```

I don't know why I cannot raise the maximum limit ?

thanks for your suggestions .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the python documentation:

> Raises ValueError if an invalid resource is specified, if the new soft
>   limit exceeds the hard limit, or if a process tries to raise its hard
>   limit (unless the process has an effective UID of super-user). Can
>   also raise error if the underlying system call fails.

From this I guess that your attempt new soft limit is too large. You probably need to rewrite you algorithm to be iterative. Python's not really designed to handle massive recursion like this.

Comment: thx, I did it iteratively, python is not designed for such a large recursive algorithm

Answer (score 4):

While it is probably a better idea to write a more effecient algo, you can raise the hard limit by running python as root (as is mentioned in the docs).

If you execute as `root`, you can actually set the stack size to unlimited with the following line :

```
import resource
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (resource.RLIM_INFINITY, resource.RLIM_INFINITY))
```

Comment: I am root. Executing `python3` in a terminal, importing `resource` and setting the limits like this raises a `ValueError: not allowed to raise maximum limit`.