# How to set max number of concurrent files to be opened for parallelized operations in .py file

Tags: python, flask

in the .py file, it contains flask webservices and that .py file contains mutltiple parallelized code. so, each time i want to run the .py file using the commnds mentioned in the code section mentioned below, i have to spcify the number of the concurrent opened files
via the following command:

```
ulimit -n 100000
```

however,this .py file will be accessed by other users and it will be invoked from the server.
my question is, is there any way to set the command `ulimit -n 100000` in .py file instead of set it manually from the console?

**code**

```
ulimit -n 100000
export FLASK_APP=webservice.py
flask run -h 1xx.xx.xxx.xx -p 8187
```

Comment: I don't think its possible

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [`resource.setrlimit`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/resource.html#resource.setrlimit):

```
import resource
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (100000, 100000))
```

Comment: after trying the code you provided, i am getting "ValueError: not allowed to raise maximum limit"..i referred to this answer "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155301/python-valueerror-not-allowed-to-raise-maximum-limit" by @Hemanshu Vadehra but it did not solve the issue

Comment: Well, the error does tell you what's happening, doesn't it? The maximum file limit imposed by your operating system is less than 100,000, and a process can't raise it by itself (unless being run as root).